# How does VS builds a project so that all classes become part of a the same assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clr, metadata, .net-assembly

Can you explain how Visual Studio builds a project (for example a console appl.) so that all

classes within the project **looks like defined in the same assembly**?

..

Or let me put it in this way:

When I open the built assembly with ILDASM, why the metadata for all the classes within the

same project are shown under '**TypeDef' metadata table**? But why not in the TypeRef?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [TypeDef vs TypeRef](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/03/23/typedef-vs-typeref.aspx) (a blog post):

> A TypeDef refers to a type definition within a scope. A TypeRef refs to a TypeDef in another scope.
>
> So a TypeDef is the "real type definition". Whereas a TypeRef just refers to a type you imported from another module.

So it makes perfect sense for an assembly to include a `TypeDef` for everything in the project, and a `TypeRef` for everything referred to in other assemblies from that project.

Comment: So my understanding is VS sets the PROJECT as the scope. But how does it call the csc.exe to instruct the compiler about the 'Project' ? csc have no idea about PROJECT concept. I am just curious how it can be done via command line by calling csc.exe

Comment: @pencilCake: Just give `csc` all the source files... `csc Foo.cs Bar.cs` etc. (Or do the same thing through msbuild, of course.)

Comment: So scope is defined as the union of the source inputs provided to csc -or MSBUILD -in a way (from the compiler point of view)

Comment: @pencilCake: In C# language terms, that's the *program*. Basically the contents of the assembly it's producing. It gets more complicated when the assembly has more than one module, of course, but you rarely need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks Jon! It was really helpful. -And also the link is very useful.